# Why jQuery .click() works only on second click with a Rails destroy link_to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails 5.2.4.2 project.
I have a "bio" resource" and a table that shows all instances of this resource with 3 buttons: "show", "edit" and "destroy" per row.
What I'm trying to do is to delete with AJAX the row of an instance when I click on the destroy button in this row.

I must say that my jQuery code is working fine but I need to click one time on the destroy button before jQuery works. And when it starts to work, it works with every other destroy button in the table.

To be more clear, what I am trying to do is exactly the same effect as in this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyPA6kJqATo

This is driving me crazy for 2 entire days now. I've tried hundreds of different ways to do it, even with pure Javascripts but I still got the same issue : I need to click one time to "activate" remove method.

Here is one version of my code :

**_biotab.html.erb:**

```
        <% @bios.each do |bio| %>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"> <%= bio.id %> </th>
                <td> <%= link_to bio.title, bio_path(bio), class:"post-title" %> </td>
                <td> <%= link_to 'Afficher', bio_path(bio) %> </td>
                <td> <%= link_to 'Editer', edit_bio_path(bio) %> </td>
                <td> <%= link_to 'Supprimer', bio, method: :delete, class: "delbtn", remote: true %> </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$(".delbtn").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Maybe the closest `<tr>` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes it is.
When jQuery starts to work, it works fine, it deletes the good <tr>. But it starts to work after one first click on the destroy button. Not on the first click. This is my problem.
Thanks !

Comment: Sorry I was assuming the jQuery was working but just didn't get the expected results.  Maybe it's deleting something, but you're not quite sure what it's deleting.  What results do you get when you show what you're deleting?  Have jQuery inspect the element being deleted.